# MySQL NOT LIKE is there a better way to do this

Tags: mysql

I currently have a query that makes sure a number of terms aren't in the `title` or `description` fields like so:

```
" ... title NOT LIKE '%word1% AND description NOT LIKE '%word1%' AND title NOT LIKE '%word2%' AND description NOT LIKE '%$word2%' ..."
```

Is there a better way of doing this as the number of words is going to grow and looking at the query it just doesn't look efficient.

Comment: I'm afraid for that requirement you don't have many other options. It would be interesting to see some good alternatives to `LIKE` for this situation

Comment: What do you mean _"doesn't look efficient"_ ?

Comment: It just doesn't look right to have a load NOT LIKES for each keyword.  I was hoping there might be something like ...NOT LIKE (keyword1,keyword2,keyword3) and I was just missing the syntax

Answer (score 0):

For different word you will have to use conditions however you can shorten ur query and get performance with help of below query : 
`and (instr(title,'word1')<=0 and instr(description,'word1')<=0) and (instr(title,'word2')<=0 and instr(description,'word2')<=0)`

Comment: Sorry for earlier post. I edited my reply. Earlier I gave a short reply but i was meant this.

Comment: Despite it was not my downvote, your post is still not correct. You __can not__ use `CONCAT()` in this case. If you're matching against `"foo"` and your `title` is `aaaaf`, `description` is `oobbbb`, then query will filter them while they should be included in result

Comment: Yes you are right sir. let me edit it otherwise it will be problem for others. However here my key point is only to inform user that use instr instead of not like for better performance. However for different word he need use multiple condition as using REGEXP is also costlier. Thank you for pointing mistake.

Comment: And why are you so sure that it will be faster than `LIKE` ?

Comment: Well, you're wrong. Sample, `select benchmark(1E7, instr('foobarfoo', 'bar')<=0)` result in `3.51 sec` while `select benchmark(1E7, 'foobarfoo' not like '%bar%')` result in `2.19 sec` for me (MySQL 5.5). So, please, do not spread info that you've not checked

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
(title NOT REGEXP 'word1|word2|word3') AND (description NOT REGEXP 'word1|word2|word3');
```

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: REGEXP is a killer.Use it only when 110% needed. Test with [BENCHMARK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_benchmark) 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/29461 : 
Using LIKE: **2232ms**
Using REGEXP: **14099ms**

Comment: Yep, just tried and it was much less inefficient - although it did work.   Thanks for the idea though